# PHP/GD image mapping/texturing

Tags: php, image, gd

I'm trying to create a produkt configurator similar to: http://winmap.active-online.de/kler/pol/index.php3?room_name=200D
I'd like to put texture or color on diffrent image elements and put it together into one result image.

I'm trying to usa like this:

```
  header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$poszycie = imagecreatefrompng('poszycie.png');
$tekstura = imagecreatefrompng('tekstura.png'); 
//imagefilter($poszycie,IMG_FILTER_EMBOSS);
//imagepng($tekstura);

//$bcg = imagecreatefromjpeg('las.jpg');
//$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('zdjecie.jpg');

//imagecopymerge($poszycie, $tekstura, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($poszycie), imagesy($poszycie), 75);
//imagepng($poszycie, null, 100);

imagecopymerge($poszycie, $tekstura, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($poszycie), imagesy($poszycie), 50);

imagepng($poszycie);
```

but result is :http://saveur.pl/testgd/configurator.png

Thanks for any help.

Comment: non english variable name... no good

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be better off with ImageMagick. For example you could use these tricks http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=14513&start=15 and I'm sure a web search for `imagemagick texture image area` would reveal more ideas.

Anyway you'll have to take apart the image and use the alpha channel.

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913284/php-gd-transparent-areas-goes-black/5913879#5913879) can help. The problem deals with alpha channel. Besides, you should send this header (png instead of jpeg):

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

since you are calling

```
imagepng($poszycie);
```

which may be another cause of trouble.