# Ci4/ image upload/ png/ transparent background becomes black

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, png

For some unknown reason, when I upload a png with a transparent background via my script, the background turns black.  If I manually upload the same png with a transparent background, it works perfectly.  Any pointers appreciated.

```
    public function update_site_logo_app_setting(){
    $appSettingModel = model('\App\Models\AppSettingModel');
    if ($this->request->getMethod() == "post") {
        $validation =  \Config\Services::validation();    
        $rules = [
            "dh_site_logo" => [
                "label" => "Site Logo", 
                "rules" => 
                'uploaded[dh_site_logo]'
                . '|is_image[dh_site_logo]'
                . '|mime_in[dh_site_logo,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png,image/webp]'
                . '|max_size[dh_site_logo,200000]'
                . '|max_dims[dh_site_logo,500,150]',
            ],
        ];
        if ( $this->validate($rules) ){
            $x_file = $this->request->getFile('dh_site_logo');
            $x_file_name = $x_file->getName();
            $image = \Config\Services::image()
                    ->withFile($x_file)
                    ->save(FCPATH . $x_file_name);
            $data[] = array(
                'app_setting_key'   => 'dh_site_logo',
                'app_setting_value' => $x_file_name,
            );
            $count = $appSettingModel->update_general_app_setting_batch( $data, 'app_setting_key');
            if ($count > 0) {
                 $this->cache_delete();
                return redirect()->to('/admin/settings')
                    ->with('info', 'Success - settings updated!');                 
            } else {
                return redirect()->back()
                ->with('warning', 'Nothing to Update')
                ->withInput();
            }
        } else {
            // return the validation errors.
            return redirect()->back()
                ->with('errors', $validation->getErrors())
                ->with('warning', 'Invalid Data')
                ->withInput();
        }
    }
}
```

So basis the research I did, it seems I need to set the transparent color.  How do I know what color PNG uses to set the transparent color?  Is is always black?  How do I say make the transparent color black?

Comment: is upload image success?

Comment: Yes, everything works.  The transparent part is black.

Comment: Seems I somehow need to work in these two method to above script but not sure how.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913284/php-gd-transparent-areas-goes-black